# Bibtex not compiling every item into the .bbl file

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper for JAIR using their style guide and APA style for my references. I have all my citations \cite{name here} in the body of my work. However, when compiling pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTex the compiler crashes and gives warnings for half of my references.

For Example:
LaTeX Warning: Citation `palacios_diagnosis_2010' on page 7 undefined. on input line 274.

I have confirmed in the Bibtex document that they are correct syntactically however Bibtex, either in that combination stated above or standalone is not compiling all of the references into the .bbl file.

The most confusing thing is that I also have a separate project for my thesis and all the references are compiling in that document.

Comment: check the blg-file for clues. If you don't find one you will have to make a complete example. It is quite difficult to debug a problem without any data and code.

Comment: Do you have a `\cite` entry for every entry in the `.bib` file?  If not, and you want every reference listed, add `\nocite{*}` to your input, to include the ones that aren't explicitly cited.